# Error 'Expected tuple, got str' in dataframes concatenation

Tags: pandas

I was trying to concatenate 2 dataframes with identical columns. Dataframes look like below:
[image]

The code I used to concatenate is pd.concat([df0914,df2016]).
The full error message is as below:
[image]

I've unified data type from the same columns of 2 dataframes. What does error message mean?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figure it out. Just in case, anyone encounter the same problem as I did. When I name the columns, I used:

```
df2016.columns=[['YEAR','COMM_CODE','RESIDENCE COUNT','0-4','5-14','15-19','20-24','25-34','35-44','45-54','55-64','65-74','75+']]
```

which gives MultiIndex([(           'YEAR',),
(      'COMM_CODE',),
('RESIDENCE COUNT',),
(            '0-4',),
(           '5-14',),
(          '15-19',),
(          '20-24',),
(          '25-34',),
(          '35-44',),
(          '45-54',),
(          '55-64',),
(          '65-74',),
(            '75+',)],
)
when I check columns. The columns is tuples, all because I should 've used one layer of [] when I was naming columns. I was so stupid.